# how to connect two functons in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am want to connect two functions: In first function(firstf.m),i want to make a 'for' loop to variables p,r then I calculat [s] for each value then i use this value in second function accuracy that should repeat 100 time The first function is

```
 [s] = firstf(data,k,opts)
 p = 30;
 if isfield(opts,'p')
 p = opts.p;
 end
 for r = 20:22;
 if isfield(opts,'r')
 r = opts.r;
 .
 .
 .
 .
 [s] = k_means(U,k)
```

So how to make for loop for variables p,r in first function and take every [s] (output of first function ) to calculate accuracy (second function) that should repeat 100 times

Comment: You are missing a significant amount of your code. Please provide both functions that you have so far as well as all of the relevant loops.

Answer (score 0):

You should call for both function each iteration.

I mean
(pseudo code)

```
for (iteration range)
  call first function and store result as variable
  call second function using last line variable
  store both results into a vector
end
```

I'm not sure if it fix your problem. If you could be more explicit in your problem, I could help you

Comment: sorry i don't know apply above pseudo code
 i will write my problem in another meaning ,the first code 
[s] = firstf(data,k,opts)
p = 30;
r = 20;
.
[s]=k_means(U,k)
and the second function 
Accuracy=ya(data,x)
.
.
[s] = firstf(adj,x)
.
A = s(linindices);
Accuracy = mean(auc)
i want to variables p and r to take range of values and in each time calculate s using first function then calculate accuracy using second function then return to first function to take next values to variable p ,r and calculate s and so on.

Comment: Mate, please format it... It's hard to interpret what you posted!